# Apache titan stable version and documentation

Tags: apache, graph-databases, titan

Am new to **Apache Titan**, can anybody help me knowing the `stable version of Apache Titan.`

Somewhere i read that **stable release is 0.3.2 is that true?** but i can see the latest version 0.5.4. so there is no stable version between 0.3.2 to 0.5.4. ?

And also if 0.3.2  is the stable version `where can i find the documents for 0.3.2 version?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.5.4` is the latest stable release:

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/

If you read somewhere that `0.3.2` is the most recent stable version, that documentation is well out of date at this point.

Comment: I havent read in any link that 0.5.4 is a stable version.https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki tells 0.4 and 0.3 are  stable and 0.5 is under development.  https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads tells 0.3 is stable and 0.4 is experimental.  which is the outdated document and which one to consider

Comment: And also i have one more question posted here, can you please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697090/matching-elasticsearch-data-indexed-by-titan

Comment: The wiki is an archive and has been left un-edited since 0.4.x.  Please use 0.5.4.

Comment: Thanks, Titan conceptually good but lack of documentation and example.